# reactjs can I flat an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code:

```
usersArray.forEach(user => {
   users.push(data.Users.filter(userAws => userAws.Username === user.username))
 });
```

this returns Arrays in Arrays.

[image]

But I want to add the inner Object direktly to the outher Array.

How can I flatten the inner Array?

thanks

**UPDATE**

```
usersArray.forEach(user => {
            users.push([].concat.apply([], data.Users.filter(userAws => userAws.Username === user.username)))
        });
```

Comment: Maybe lodash's `flatten` method can help you. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatten

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: @marvinhagemeister can you explain how hat works?

Comment: @marvinhagemeister I've added an update ... but that returns the same stuff like bevore

Comment: set users to array and thenuse users.concat(data.Users.filter(userAws => userAws.Username === user.username))

Comment: when I do that I got an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is this:

```
users.push(...data.Users.filter(userAws => userAws.Username === user.username))
```